# SQL: Select data field from current row

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I select a field from the current row I am using?

For example, I have a table which looks like this:

```
C1   C2  C3     
d1       d3
```

I need to get the value of d1 to calculate the value of d2 (under column C2).

How do I do within SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question (How do I select a field from the current row I am using?) is

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE criterion
```

You have not told us the name of your table.

What you do tell us allows for different interpretations.  Conceivably when you say "I need to get the value of d1 to calculate the value of d2 (under column C2)" you mean

```
SELECT C2 FROM table_name WHERE C1 = d1
```

but as you can see by the widely varying answers here, it's unclear exactly what you wish to do.

Answer (score 2):

**You're thinking about relational databases wrongly** - the individual rows are in no particular order so this isn't possible in its current form.

You'll likely have to redisign the database - if you could describe what these elements are I'm sure you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 2):

For updating try:

```
Update Table1
SET C2 = C1+C3
WHERE /*SELECTION CRETERIA*/
```